# How to add a map object to mysql in nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, dictionary

It's my first time creating a map object and I'm trying to add it to a mysql database but I have an error that says: **"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`key` = '#42343731'' at line 1"**.

Examples of elements inside the map object are the following:

```
Map {
'#44928649' => {
  id: '#44928649',
  name: '508',
  year: '2020',
  price: 34800,
  included_tax: true,
  state: true
},
 '#44899990' => {
 id: '#44899990',
 name: 'yaris',
 year: '2018',
 price: 17800,
 included_tax: true,
 state: true
 }
}
```

My query is the following:

```
 function addNewElement(value, key, map){
           connection.query("INSERT INTO test(id, name, year, price, included_tax, status) VALUES ?", {key}, (err, res) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("new element: ", res.insertId)
            });
 }
 carsList.forEach(addNewElement);
```

I think I'm not doing right the way to add the elements inside the query. Another question I have is, do you recommend maintaining the array inside the value of every key of the map or do you think it is better to make them maps as well?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `{key}` is returning the key of the map you defined. i.e. '#44928649' or '#44899990'.

This means that your SQL statement looks as follows: 
`INSERT INTO test(id, name, year, price, included_tax, status) VALUES '#44928649'`

#### What you need to do is return the value of the key in the map

Try the following:

```
connection.query("INSERT INTO test (id, name, year, price, included_tax, status) SET ?", value, (err, res)...
```

Comment: I see! You are completely right! However, it seems that now I have this error  "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1"
What do you think it could be? Thanks!

Comment: Just confirm for me, did you copy+paste `"... VALUES ?"` ?

Comment: No, I've changed the {key} to key[map], I will try to see if it is a problem of some typo that I did

Comment: It doesn't work either, could it be because of the loop? I double checked if there was any typo but seems everything correct

Comment: try add a space between `test` and the column names. See the updated query

Comment: Your first answer was totally right! the second mistake was because it is inside an asynchronous function, I ad to promisify the connection and make the query await. Thanks for the help!